# Ruby program to retrieve OpenStreetMap data using OSM API

Tags: ruby, api, openstreetmap

How can I retrieve data from OpenStreetMap (OSM) using the OSM API (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) and Ruby? Is there any ruby gem available which serves my purpose? I have been searching for a good solution for my purpose but nothing served me exactly what I need.
As for example : Given the country name as input, I need to get the list of all streets of that country etc. 
Any kind of link/code sample or starting point is fine. I can then explore more to find out what I need exactly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question as posed is off topic for Stack Overflow, I will answer the question of "How to find something I can use" rather than give any kind of recommendation on a tool itself.

I am not familiar with any gems for OpenStreetMap.

So I do this command from the terminal:

```
gem list --remote | grep street
```

And my terminal answers me with this:

```
openstreetmap (0.2.1)
```

And then I pull up my trusty browser, and open up ruby-toolbox.org and search for openstreetmap.

This produces a page that shows 30 results.  In there, I see the mentioned gem, but also I see `Rosemary` which seems promising, as it is an "OpenStreetMap API client for ruby" and it was last updated only 4 months ago.

So, hopefully this helps in future searches.  You have a lot of tools available to get started on your search to get to the point you are asking for in this question, so that you can get down to the business of doing what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The [main API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) you want to use is not suitable for such queries. It is mainly for editing and retrieving *small* amounts of map data within a *small* region. For larger queries better use the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) which is much faster and also allows very [complex query conditions](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide) if needed.

The Overpass API uses XML as input and serves either XML or JSON as output format. So it should be rather easy to use in any common scripting language.